# Grabbing only text/substring between 4th and 7th underscores in all lines of a file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, substring

I have a list.txt which contains the following lines.

```
Primer_Adapter_clean_KL01_BOLD1_100_KL01_BOLD1_100_N701_S507_L001_merged.fasta
Primer_Adapt_clean_KL01_BOLD1_500_KL01_BOLD1_500_N704_S507_L001_merged.fasta
Primer_Adapt_clean_LD03_BOLD2_Sessile_LD03_BOLD2_Sessile_N710_S506_L001_merged.fasta
```

Now I would like to grab only the substring between the 4th underscore and 7th underscore such that it will appear as below

```
BOLD1_100_KL01
BOLD1_500_KL01
BOLD2_Sessile_LD03
```

I tried the below awk command but I guess I've got it wrong. Any help here would be appreciated. If this can be achieved via sed, I would be interested in that solution too.

```
awk -v FPAT="[^__]*" '$4=$7' list.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="_"} {print $5,$6,$7}' file
```

Output:

```
BOLD1_100_KL01
BOLD1_500_KL01
BOLD2_Sessile_LD03
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel like `awk` is overkill for this. You can just use [`cut`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cut.1p.html) to select just the fields you want:

```
$ cut -d_ -f5-7 list.txt
BOLD1_100_KL01
BOLD1_500_KL01
BOLD2_Sessile_LD03
```